# Show $1+\frac{8q}{1-q}+\frac{16q^2}{1+q^2}+\frac{24q^3}{1-q^3}+\dots=1+\frac{8q}{(1-q)^2}+\frac{8q^2}{(1+q^2)^2}+\frac{8q^3}{(1-q^3)^2}+\dots$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, q-series, double-sequence

Show that $$1+\frac{8q}{1-q}+\frac{16q^2}{1+q^2}+\frac{24q^3}{1-q^3}+\dots=1+\frac{8q}{(1-q)^2}+\frac{8q^2}{(1+q^2)^2}+\frac{8q^3}{(1-q^3)^2}+\dots$$
where $|q|<1$ (q can be complex number).

The hint is to convert the left side to a double series.

One can see that the nominators on the left side is double, triple, ... of those on the right side, while denominators on the right side are square of those on the left side. Both sides have 1, which seems redundant.

> I'm not sure how to proceed from these observations. Any advice will be helpful. I can try to solve it with some suggestion and if I still can't solve it I will then explain what puzzles me. If anyone gives the answer I guess I will look at only part of it and work from that.

---

**Edits:**

I post my answer inspired by the comments and some other thoughts about the question below.

Is there any other ways to solve it?

Comment: Are you asking a question, or are you providing us with a problem for us to solve for you ?

Comment: Why don't you convert this into a double series to begin with? Ignoring $1$ we can write the series on left as $8\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nq^n} {1-(-q)^n}$ which can be written as $$8\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nq^n\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} (-q) ^{mn} $$

Comment: I see, I will try some.

Comment: Now swap the order of summation to get $$8\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^{mn}nq^{n(m+1)}$$

Comment: It's $\frac{nq^n}{1+(-q)^n}$?

Comment: I guess the added 'q-series' tag may be helpful.

Comment: I think the 'index' thinking provides some help.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thanks for the hint

Comment: Nice approach .

Comment: This is how one makes use of hints in comments. I will suggest to remove your solution from the question body and post it as an answer. And you may accept your answer to remove this question from unanswered list. Also thanks for catching typo in my comment.

Comment: The $q$-series is the generating function of [OEIS sequence A000118](https://oeis.org/A000118) "Number of ways of writing n as a sum of 4 squares; also theta series of lattice Z^4." which may give you ideas.

Comment: So a generating function is like $ \theta_3(q)^4 = (\prod_{n=1..\infty} (1-q^{(2n)})\cdot(1+q^{(2n-1)})^2 )^4 = \eta(-q)^8/\eta(q^2)^4$; where $\eta=$ Dedekind's function $q^{1/24}\prod(1-q^n)$ where q is unit complex number in the upper half complex plane https://calculushowto.com/holomorphic-function/#dedekind.
In this paper, https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9206203.pdf the formula a' looks quite like the series dealt with here.
It seems we have 8 in the formula because it's the module? https://www.alpertron.com.ar/4SQUARES.HTM @Somos

Comment: But I'm still wondering why we need so many different functions to calc Number of ways of writing n as a sum of 4 squares (which is supposed to be unique)? Is it similar to the case of partition problem in number theory? (i.e. these functions are to give approximate results when n is large?)

Comment: Perhaps we can try to prove series on both sides give the number of ways of writing an integer as a sum of 4 squares, and then show the '=' is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one way is to try to decompose the series to product of two absolutely convergent series, another way is to prove in general what makes $\sum\frac{na_n}{b_n}=\sum\frac{a_n}{(b_n)^2}$; or I can check if the equation is valid for all q and see if I can get some ideas.

I try to decompose the series as $\sum \frac{n(\sqrt{q})^n(\sqrt{q})^n}{1+(i\sqrt{q})^{2n}}=\sum \frac{n(\sqrt{q})^n(\sqrt{q})^n}{1-(i\sqrt{q})^{2n}i^2}=\sum\frac{n(\sqrt{q})^n(\sqrt{q})^n}{(1-(i\sqrt{q})^{n}i)(1+(i\sqrt{q})^{n}i)},$ which is a product of two absolutely convergent series. Is it possible to proceed from that?

I guess a problem I encounter here is that I can't introduce another index, or even make the series product of two (perhaps absolutely convergent) series with independent indexes.

(Well, perhaps I should make it more explicit that it's not exactly
$$1+\frac{8q}{1+q}+\frac{16q^2}{1-q^2}+\frac{24q^3}{1+q^3}+\dots,$$

which is very similar to the above series. One may not express the denominators elegantly, which I guess is something one naturally pursues, but at least in this case it doesn’t hinder us from finding a nice  solution.)

However, the two actually work the same way. (Note that **$1/(1-a)$, instead of $1/(1-a^n)$, expands to $1+a+a^2+...$** this is exactly where I get trapped.)

---

Here is the solution I get by far:
$$\frac{q}{1+q}+\frac{2q^2}{1-q^2}+\frac{3q^3}{1+q^3}+\dots
=\sum \frac{nq^n}{1-(-)^{n+1}q^n}\\
=\sum_{n=1} nq^n\sum_{m=0} ((-)^{n+1}q^n)^m\\
=\sum_{m=0}\sum_{n=1} (-)^{m}n[(-)^{m}q^{m+1}]^n,$$

which, **for $\sum_{n=1} nt^n=\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$** , equals
$$\sum_{m=0} (-)^{m}\frac{(-)^{m}q^{m+1}}{(1-(-)^{m}q^{m+1})^2}=\sum_{m=0} \frac{q^{m+1}}{(1-(-)^{m}q^{m+1})^2},$$

and so we get the result.

In a word, $\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{m=0} t^m, \sum_{n=1} nt^n=\frac{t}{(1-t)^2}$, this is how we go from the left side to the right.

The double series is like:

$1\ \ \ \ \ \ (1\ +0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +0^2+...\ \ \ \ \ )$

$8q\ \ \ \ (1\ +q\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +q^2+...\ \ \ \ \ )$

$16q^2(1\ +(-q^2)\ +(-q^2)^2...)$

And **for the series converges absolutely, the row sum (left side) and the column sum (right side) is the same**, which completes the proof.

This example illustrates a condition for switching the order of summing indexes, as well as how to recognize patterns. Also, $nq^n$ and $q^n$ are exactly the two absolute convergent series that I was looking for, though I got the latter not by breaking each item on the left to a prduct, but by using Taylor expansion. From that one can see matrix, indexing, (double) series, (Taylor) expansion are much related.

PS: a hindsight, one may view the problem from another way. The sum of nominator $8nq^n$ in the series is obviously convergent, while the denominator is not, so we may regard it as a limit of infinite series, i.e. a sum, instead of as an item in the series.

Comment: The two sums are not equal. [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dq1psdw19o) is a graph of them

Comment: [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xc5xh7xndd) is a graph of the coefficients of $q^n$ when the two sums are expanded into a power series in $q$. The coefficient for the $q$-series on the left is $$f_1(n)=(-1)^n\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+n/d-1}2^d,$$ and the coefficient of the $q$-series on the right is $$f_2(n)=(-1)^n2\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+n/d-1}\tfrac{n}{d}.$$

Answer (score 3):

These series are not equal for all $|q|<1$. Here's an explanation.

First, let
$$A(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{1-bq^n},\qquad |bq|<1$$
and $$B(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2},\qquad |bq|<1.$$
Let
$$F_1(q)=A(-2,-1;-q)=\frac{2q}{1-q}+\frac{4q}{1+q^2}+\frac{8q^3}{1-q^3}+...$$
and $$F_2(q)=B(-1,-1;-q)=\frac{q}{(1-q)^2}+\frac{q^2}{(1+q^2)^2}+\frac{q^3}{(1-q^3)^2}+...$$

> You assert that $$1+4F_1(q)=1+8F_2(q).\tag{*}$$ **This is incorrect.** Below is an explanation.

---

First of all, define the functions $\phi_n,\sigma_n:\Bbb R\times\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ to satisfy
$$\begin{align}
A(a,b;q)&=\sum_{n\ge1}\phi_n(a,b)q^n\\
B(a,b;q)&=\sum_{n\ge1}\sigma_n(a,b)q^n.
\end{align}$$
Then we can see that
$$\begin{align}
A(a,b;q)&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{1-bq^n}\\
&=\frac1b\sum_{n\ge1}a^n\frac{bq^n}{1-bq^n}\\
&=\frac1b\sum_{n\ge1}a^n\sum_{k\ge1}b^kq^{nk}\\
&=\frac1b\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{k\ge1}a^nb^kq^{nk}\\
&=\frac1b\sum_{m\ge1}q^m\sum_{nk=m}a^nb^k\\
&=\sum_{m\ge1}q^m\sum_{d|n}a^db^{m/d-1}.
\end{align}$$
Thus $$\phi_n(a,b)=\sum_{d|n}a^db^{n/d-1}.$$
Then, preform the index shift $d=n/j$ for $j|n$:
$$\phi_n(a,b)=\sum_{j|n}a^{n/j}b^{j-1}=\frac{a}{b}\sum_{j|n}b^ja^{n/j-1}=\frac{a}{b}\phi_n(b,a).\tag1$$

Then take $\partial_b=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}$ of $A(a/q,b;q)$:
$$\begin{align}
\partial_b A(a/q,b;q)&=\sum_{n\ge1}\partial_b\frac{a^n}{1-bq^n}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2}\\
&=B(a,b;q).
\end{align}$$
Then from $(1)$, we have that $A(a,b;q)=\frac{a}{b}A(b,a;q)$, so that
$$\begin{align}
A(a/q,b;q)&=\frac{a}{bq}A(b,a/q;q)\\
&=a\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(bq)^{n-1}}{1-aq^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{a}{1-a}+a\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(bq)^{n}}{1-aq^{n}}\\
&=\frac{a}{1-a}+bA(a,b;q).
\end{align}$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
B(a,b;q)&=\partial_b A(a/q,b;q)\\
&=\partial_b \left\{\frac{a}{1-a}+bA(a,b;q)\right\}\\
&=\partial_b bA(a,b;q)\\
&=A(a,b;q)+b\partial_b A(a,b;q)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\phi_n(a,b)+\sum_{n\ge1}q^nb\partial_b \phi_n(a,b)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\left\{\sum_{d|n}a^db^{n/d-1}+b\sum_{d|n}\left(\tfrac{n}{d}-1\right)a^db^{n/d-2}\right\}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\sum_{d|n}\tfrac{n}{d}a^db^{n/d-1}.
\end{align}$$
Hence $$\sigma_n(a,b)=\sum_{d|n}\tfrac{n}{d}a^db^{n/d-1}.$$

---

Since $F_1(q)=A(-2,-1;-q)$ and $F_2(q)=B(-1,-1;-q)$, we have
$$F_1(q)=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\cdot\left((-1)^n\phi_n(-2,-1)\right)=\sum_{n\ge1}p_1(n)q^n,$$
and
$$F_2(q)=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\cdot\left((-1)^n\sigma_n(-1,-1)\right)=\sum_{n\ge1}p_2(n)q^n.$$
Then your claim $(*)$ is equivalent to $p_1(n)=2p_2(n)$, or
$$\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+n/d-1}2^d=2\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+n/d-1}\frac{n}{d}.\tag{*'}$$
So $(*)$ is true if and only if $(*')$ is true.

To check this, let
$$f(n)=\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+n/d-1}(2^d-2n/d).$$
$(*)$ Is true if and only if $f(n)$ is identical to $0$.

> It is quite easy to show that $f(3)=-(2-6)-(2^3-2)=-2$, so $f(n)$ is not identical to $0$ and your claim is false.

Comment: I spent a month trying to prove that your claim was true, but it only took me 10 minutes to figure out it was false.