# Concerning the coefficient $[q^n]\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, generating-functions, analytic-number-theory, q-series

Background:

While trying to answer [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3782985/583016), I came up with a question of my own.

Let $|a|,|b|,|q|<1$ and
$$A(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{1-bq^n}.$$
One can show that $$A(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\phi_n(a,b)q^n,$$
where $$\phi_n(a,b)=\sum_{d|n}a^db^{n/d-1}.$$
Preforming the index shift $j=n/d$, we can write
$$\phi_n(a,b)=\sum_{j|n}a^{n/j}b^{j-1}=\frac{a}{b}\phi_n(b,a).$$
Thus $$A(a,b;q)=\frac{a}{b}A(b,a;q).\tag1$$
Then let $$B(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{(1-bq^n)^2},$$
and we can see that
$$B(a,b;q)=\frac{\partial}{\partial b}A(a/q,b;q).$$
Then let $\sigma_n(a,b)=[q^n]B(a,b;q)$.

> Do these coefficients satisfy a similar symmetry under $(a,b)\mapsto (b,a)$ that $\phi_n$ does? In other words, is there a 'nice' relationship between $B(a,b;q)$ and $B(b,a;q)$?

My attempts are below.

I tried setting $M(a,b;q)=A(a/q,b;q)$, and I noticed that
$$\begin{align}
M(a,b;q)&=\frac{a}{bq}A(b,a/q;q)\\
&=a\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(bq)^{n-1}}{1-aq^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{a}{1-a}+a\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(bq)^{n}}{1-aq^{n}}\\
&=\frac{a}{1-a}+bA(a,b;q).
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$\begin{align}
B(a,b;q)&=\partial_b bA(a,b;q)\\
&=A(a,b;q)+b\partial_b A(a,b;q)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\phi_n(a,b)+\sum_{n\ge1}q^nb\partial_b \phi_n(a,b)\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\left\{\sum_{d|n}a^db^{n/d-1}+b\sum_{d|n}\left(\tfrac{n}{d}-1\right)a^db^{n/d-2}\right\}\\
&=\sum_{n\ge1}q^n\sum_{d|n}\tfrac{n}{d}a^db^{n/d-1}.
\end{align}$$
Thus $$\sigma_n(a,b)=\sum_{d|n}\tfrac{n}{d}a^db^{n/d-1},$$
which we can write as $$\sigma_n(a,b)=\frac{a}{b}\sum_{d|n}db^da^{n/d-1},$$
which looks a lot like $\frac{a}{b}\sigma_n(b,a)$, but [this is not so](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/flabzxuhab).

> At this point I am at a loss for a formula that relates $\sigma_n(a,b)$ and $\sigma_n(b,a)$, so could I have some help? Thanks!

---

Edit: I took the liberty of posting this question on Math Overflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/377028/130062).

Comment: +1 there. It appears that you have been charmed by $q$ series and are well on your way for some real fun out there.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh it us true... I can't get enough!

Comment: Just a thought. In typical usage of $q$ series I see that $a, b$ take the values $\pm 1$ and nothing else.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh do you think it is realistic to expect a nice equation relating $\sigma_n(a,b)$ and $\sigma_n(b,a)$?

Comment: Right now I can't think of an obvious relationship of the kind you desire. Let's hope some experts in $q$ series arrive on the scene and provide some useful ideas.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Since we may write $$\frac{u_1}{1-v}+\frac{u_2}{1-v}=\frac{u_1+u_2-vu_1-vu_2}{(1-v)^2},$$ we have, upon plugging in $u_i=(a_iq)^n$ and $v=bq^n$ then summing, $$A(a_1,b;q)+A(a_2,b;q)=B(a_1,b;q)+B(a_2,b;q)-2b(B(a_1q,b;q)+B(a_2q,b;q)).$$ Do you think this could be helpful?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Indeed it can be shown that $$A(a,b;q)-B(a,b;q)=-bB(aq,b;q)$$