# Finding rational points of $f(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/(x^n+y^n)$ for real $x$, $y$

Tags: number-theory

This function has some obvious rational points (e.g. $x$ equals a rational and $y$ equals $0$, or $x=y$), and it's also fairly intuitive that this sum converges a lot of the time. What's less obvious to me is a way of proving irrationality of this function's values, as much as I'd be surprised if there were random rational points out there in the universe given that even $x=2$ and $y=1$ gives an irrational sum. I've looked for an obvious trick but can't find one.

Presumably there's something to be said about transcendentality too, but that's beyond my paygrade.

Edit: An example of closed forms clearly existing for some values of this function, ones that clearly aren't rational

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n+1^n}=-1+\frac{\Psi_{0.5}^{(0)}\big(1-\frac{i\pi}{log(2)}\big)}{log(2)}\approx0.7644+0.0\times10^{-5}i$$

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the answer you want, but I think it might be the closest you're gonna get.

**Part 1: 'closed forms'**
It is unlikely that there are any non-trivial closed form evaluations for $f(x,y)$ in terms of well-studied constants. Really, the 'closed form' for $f(2,1)$ you identified is not much of a closed form at all. Specifically,
$$f(2,1)=-1+\frac{1}{\log2}\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}(1-i\pi/\log2),\tag1$$
uses the function $\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}$ which is a special case of the $q$-polygamma function:
$$\psi_q^{(n)}(z)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)^n\psi_q(z),$$
with $$\psi_q(z)=-\log(1-q)+\log(q)\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{q^{n+z}}{1-q^{n+z}},\qquad |q|<1.$$
The derivation of $(1)$ is actually quite simple:
$$\begin{align}
\psi_{1/2}^{(0)}(1-i\pi/\log2)&=-\log(1-1/2)+\log(1/2)\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(1/2)^{n+1-i\pi/\log2}}{1-(1/2)^{n+1-i\pi/\log2}}\\
&=\log(2)-\log(2)\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{1}{2^{n+1-i\pi/\log2}-1}\\
&=\log(2)-\log(2)\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{2^{n}2^{-i\pi/\log2}-1}\\
&=\log(2)-\log(2)\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{2^{n}e^{-i\pi\log2/\log2}-1}\\
&=\log(2)+\log(2)\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{2^{n}+1}\\
&=\log(2)(1+f(2,1)).
\end{align}$$
And similarly one can show that
$$f(x,1)=\frac{1}{\log x}\left(\psi_{1/x}^{(0)}(1-i\pi/\log x)+\log(1-1/x)\right),$$
for $x>1$.
If you want an even better 'closed form', define the function
$$A(a,b;q)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(aq)^n}{1-bq^n},$$
and observe that
$$A(a,b;q)=\frac{a}{b}A(b,a;q),$$
([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3911879/583016)). It is then not hard to see that
$$f(x,y)=A(1/x,-1;x/y)=-\frac1x A(-1,1/x;x/y),\qquad y\ne0.$$
However, no matter how satisfying that is, it's no closer to a closed form than the defining expression for $f(x,y)$ is.

My point is, it is extremely unlikely that certain non-trivial values of $f(x,y)$ will yield results in terms of constants that we know anything about.

**Part 2: irrationality** Unfortunately it is actually not "clear" that $f(2,1)$ is irrational. It's not even known if Catalan's constant
$$\mathrm G=\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}$$
is rational, and we certainly know much more about $\mathrm G$ than we know about $f(2,1)$.

And of course, transcendentality is even farther out of the picture.